# Recognizing expression written in assembly containing $ and new line

Tags: regular-expression, replace

I'm trying to remove instances of the following:

```
add $t1, $zero, 9
sw $t1, 8($t4)
```

Where 9 could be any number, however 8 is consistent. If I copy this expression in Vim I get: `^Iadd $t1, $zero, 9^M^Isw $t1, 8($t4)^M`

Of course if I want to search and replace (I do) I need to escape the $. I've also tried replacing ^I with \t and ^M with \r, but can't seem to match this expression. I've tried:

```
%s/\tadd \$t1, \$zero, \d\r\tsw \$t1, 8(\$t4)//
%s/^Iadd \$t1, \$zero, 9^M^Isw \$t1, 8(\$t4)^M//
%s/\tadd $t1, $zero, 9\r\tsw $t1, 8($t4)//
```

but I can't seem to get anything to match. What am I missing here? Pretty much everything in assembly (MIPS) looks the same, so solving this problem would be quite useful

I have also tried the following:[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `very magic` mode for such searching. `^M` is actually `\n`, not `\r`. I don't see tabs in the provided excerpt, but this seems to work (without tabs):

```
\vadd \$t1, \$zero, \d\nsw \$t1, 8\(\$t4\)
```

You can add those `\t` if they're present in your text.

Comment: I tried that, but didn't seem to work. Posted screenshot results in questions.

Also, when do you use \n and when use \r? Cause usually if I want to write something for search and replace I'll use \n for new line, but if I'm trying to match a text I use \r

Comment: So maybe try to `set hlsearch` and `set incsearch` - this will make search more interactive, it will show you in real time if your search expression matches and what it matches. I test more complex patterns this way.